# Software Updater doesn't work: "Failed to download repository information (check your internet connection)"

Tags: updates

I've been hating using Windows for quite a while and I'm trying Freya as a possible substitute.

However, I can't do updates to the system.

I get a window with the warning written in the title of question. If I continue, it says sources are not trusted and after clicking to continue it does nothing. On terminal, using update command, it always shows the same things.

**EDIT**: I uninstalled the software updater and installed again. Tried some more times to update. I managed to update twice (~60Mb in first update and some Kb in second) and I have freya for 1 month. Nothing else showed up. The terminal always shows a long text with different things and errors (and download speeds etc):

Question of Daniel: I added ppa, I read in my websites that it would be a plus after installing freya. Ops?

PS: I was some time away, hence the late edits. I'm sorry if I'm not formatting correctly since all this is new to me

***EDIT2***: Thanks for the terminal tip on formatting;

"other software" tab is in "settings" inside software updater but not on "system settings". There are lots of repeated names like *recommended updates* three times, but each one has a different *component* when I click *edit* and the same applies to other update sources on the list. Should I keep them? I ran the commands in terminal (sudo clean, update, upgrade) and the output is similar and when I go to *software updater* the same updates are listed with the exception 0f 3Mb (total 67Mb) and no 0.3.1 or different things from before. I would really like to switch from Win7 to Freya but I still need to get it working (almost) perfect (e.g updates) but I'm inexperienced (I hope it's possible!!). Thanks in advance for your time

**EDIT3** So I managed to do updates (partially, couldn't install each update fully due to errors) but now I get errors: *boot partition low space* so can't install stuff without warnings nor updates. SOmehow I now have freya 0.3.1 which wasn't mentioned in the updates' list o.o

on terminal:

```
antonio@A-Computer:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for antonio: 
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to pt.archive.ub
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
6% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14)] [Connecting t
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
11% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14)] [Connecting
Get:1 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
99% [Waiting for headers] [1 Release.gpg 933 B/933 B 100%] [Waitin
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Get:2 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63,5 kB]
3% [Waiting for headers] [2 Release 1182 B/63,5 kB 2%] [Waiting fo
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease 
100% [2 Release gpgv 63,5 kB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for h
100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for head
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [3 Release.gpg 93  
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
100% [Release gpgv 63,5 kB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for hea 
100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for head
Get:4 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15,4 kB]
82% [Waiting for headers] [4 Packages 1173 B/15,4 kB 8%] [Waiting
100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for head
100% [4 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for hea 
100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for head
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63,5 kB]
57% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [5 Release 1099 B/
Get:6 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [614 kB]
13% [Waiting for headers] [6 Packages 5395 B/614 kB 1%] [5 Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                  
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
100% [7 Release.gpg 933 B/933 B 100%] [6 Packages 614 kB/614 kB 10
100% [6 Packages 614 kB/614 kB 100%] [5 Release 63,5 kB/63,5 kB 10
100% [6 Packages bzip2 0 B] [5 Release gpgv 63,5 kB] [Waiting for
100% [6 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for hea
Get:8 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [310 kB]
71% [6 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [8 Packages 2579
92% [Waiting for headers] [8 Packages 222 kB/310 kB 72%] [Waiting
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release.gpg [933 B]
99% [9 Release.gpg 933 B/933 B 100%] [8 Packages 294 kB/310 kB 95%
100% [8 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for hea
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [339 kB]
76% [8 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for head
Get:11 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [11,9 kB]
78% [8 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [11 Packages 258179% [8 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 39,1
Get:12 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15,1 kB]
78% [8 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [12 Packages 1173
79% [8 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 39,1
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
79% [8 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 39,1
79% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 39,1 
79% [11 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for hea
79% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 39,1
79% [12 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for hea
79% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 40,5
Get:13 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [595 kB]
57% [Waiting for headers] [13 Packages 3987 B/595 kB 1%] [10 Packa
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
76% [13 Packages 370 kB/595 kB 62%] [10 Packages 81,3 kB/339 kB 24
76% [Release gpgv 58,5 kB] [Waiting for headers] [13 Packages 373
77% [Waiting for headers] [13 Packages 386 kB/595 kB 65%] [10 Pack
88% [13 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for hea
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63,5 kB]
87% [13 Packages bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 3930 B/63,5 kB 6%] [Waitin
Get:15 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [311 kB]
77% [13 Packages bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 13,8 kB/63,5 kB 22%] [15 P
86% [14 Release 13,8 kB/63,5 kB 22%] [15 Packages 229 kB/311 kB 74
90% [14 Release 13,8 kB/63,5 kB 22%] [10 Packages 142 kB/339 kB 42
90% [15 Packages bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 13,8 kB/63,5 kB 22%] [Wait
Get:16 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [12,1 kB]
92% [15 Packages bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%] [16 P
92% [15 Packages bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%] [10 P
Get:17 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [297 kB]
82% [15 Packages bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%] [17 T
83% [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%] [17 Translation-en 26,5 kB/29
83% [16 Packages bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%] [17 T
83% [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%] [17 Translation-en 42,0 kB/29
93% [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%] [10 Packages 184 kB/339 kB 54
93% [17 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 30,7 kB/63,5 kB 48%]
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
96% [17 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%]
96% [Translation-en 21,7 kB] [17 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Rel
96% [17 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%]
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
96% [17 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%]
96% [Translation-en 30,3 kB] [17 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Rel
96% [17 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%]
96% [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%] [Waiting for headers] [10 Pac
Get:18 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [164 kB]
91% [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%] [18 Translation-en 1171 B/164
96% [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%] [10 Packages 236 kB/339 kB 70
96% [18 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Release 60,2 kB/63,5 kB 95%]
98% [18 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting f
98% [18 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [14 Release gpgv 63,5 kB] [Waiti
98% [18 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting f
98% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 284 k
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
98% [Packages 3396 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
98% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 284 k   
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
99% [Packages 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [10
99% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packages 319 k
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release [211 kB]
93% [19 Release 8152 B/211 kB 4%] [Waiting for headers] [10 Packag
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
94% [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [10 Packages 328 kB/339 kB 97%
94% [Packages 24,0 kB] [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [Waiting fo
94% [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [Waiting for headers] [10 Pack
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
94% [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [10 Packages 339 kB/339 kB 100
94% [Packages 160 kB] [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [Waiting for
94% [Packages 160 kB] [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 34,9 kB/
95% [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [Waiti
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
95% [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [Waiti95% [Packages 3341 B] [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 34,9 kB/95% [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 34,9 kB/211 kB 17%] [Waiti                                                                  Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
96% [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 71,5 kB/211 kB 34%] [Waiti96% [Packages 0 B] [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 71,5 kB/21196% [10 Packages bzip2 0 B] [19 Release 71,5 kB/211 kB 34%] [Waiti96% [19 Release 71,5 kB/211 kB 34%] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting                                                                  Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8875 B]
96% [19 Release 71,5 kB/211 kB 34%] [Waiting for headers] [20 Pack                                                                  Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
                                                                  96% [19 Rhttp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [324 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources       
94% [Sources 5000 kB] [Waiting for headers] [23 Packages 60,2 kB/3                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources  
98% [Sources 22,9 kB] [Waiting for headers] [23 Packages 124 kB/32                                                                  98% [Waiting for headers] [23 Packages 124 kB/324 kB 38%]                                                                           Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
98% [23 Packages 186 kB/324 kB 57%]                                                                                                 98% [Sources 27,9 MB] [Waiting for headers] [23 Packages 186 kB/32                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
99% [Sources 27,9 MB] [Waiting for headers] [23 Packages 236 kB/32                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
                                                                  100% [Sources 27,9 MB] [23 Packages 304 kB/324 kB 94%]                                                                              100% [Sources 27,9 MB] [23 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for header                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
100% [Sources 27,9 MB] [23 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for header                                                                  Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [8846 B]
100% [Sources 27,9 MB] [Waiting for headers] [24 Packages 2473 B/8                                                                  100% [Sources 27,9 MB] [24 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for header                                                                  100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]                  100% [Sources 711 kB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] 100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                    100% [Packages 8235 kB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
                                                                  100% [Packages 8235 kB] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                       Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [116 kB]
                                                                  100% [Packages 8235 kB] [Waiting for headers] [25 Packages 2470 B/                                                                  100% [Waiting for headers] [25 Packages 46,1 kB/116 kB 40%]                                                                         100% [Packages 184 kB] [Waiting for headers] [25 Packages 46,1 kB/                                                                  100% [Waiting for headers] [25 Packages 46,1 kB/116 kB 40%]                                                                         100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers] [25 Packages 46,1 kB                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                     100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [25 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for heade                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                                                               Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3830 B]
                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers] [26 Packages 3830 B/                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                     100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [26 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for heade                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                       Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [185 kB]
100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers] [27 Translation-en 5                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [27 Translation-en 81,3 kB/185 kB 44%]    100% [Waiting for headers] [27 Translation-en 84,1 kB/185 kB 45%] 100% [Packages 664 kB] [Waiting for headers] [27 Translation-en 84100% [Waiting for headers] [27 Translation-en 87,0 kB/185 kB 47%] 100% [Packages 8205 kB] [Waiting for headers] [27 Translation-en 8                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
100% [Packages 8205 kB] [27 Translation-en 167 kB/185 kB 90%]     100% [Packages 8205 kB] [Waiting for headers]                     100% [Packages 8205 kB] [27 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for                                                                  100% [27 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting                                                                   100% [Packages 185 kB] [27 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for                                                                   100% [27 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting                                                                   100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [27 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for                                                                  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [27 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for                                                                  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [27 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers                                                                  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                       Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [67,6 kB]
100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers] [28 Translation-en 5100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                       100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [28 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for                                                                  100% [Packages 31,7 MB] [Waiting for headers]                     100% [Waiting for headers]                                        100% [Packages 674 kB] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                        Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
100% [Packages 674 kB]                                            100% [Waiting for headers]                                        100% [Translation-en 5770 B] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                        100% [Translation-en 15,4 kB] [Waiting for headers]               100% [Waiting for headers]                                        100% [Translation-en 4149 kB] [Waiting for headers]               100% [Waiting for headers]                                        100% [Translation-en 409 kB] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
100% [Waiting for headers]                                        100% [Translation-en 21,2 kB] [Waiting for headers]               100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
100% [Working]                                                    100% [Translation-en 18,6 MB] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                 Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [614 kB]
100% [Translation-en 18,6 MB] [29 Packages 8117 B/614 kB 1%]      100% [29 Packages 88,4 kB/614 kB 14%]                             100% [29 Packages 293 kB/614 kB 48%]                              100% [Working]                                                    100% [29 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                  Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [310 kB]
100% [29 Packages bzip2 0 B] [30 Packages 5301 B/310 kB 2%]       100% [30 Packages 91,2 kB/310 kB 29%]                             100% [Working]                                                    100% [30 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [11,9 kB]
100% [31 Packages 5303 B/11,9 kB 44%]                             100% [Working]                                                    100% [31 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15,4 kB]
100% [32 Packages 9527 B/15,4 kB 62%]                             100% [Working]                                                    100% [32 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [595 kB]
100% [33 Packages 3893 B/595 kB 1%]                               100% [33 Packages 530 kB/595 kB 89%]                              100% [Working]                                                    100% [33 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                                                  Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [311 kB]
100% [33 Packages bzip2 0 B] [34 Packages 3893 B/311 kB 1%]       100% [34 Packages 131 kB/311 kB 42%]                              100% [Working]                                                    100% [34 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [12,1 kB]
100% [35 Packages 3895 B/12,1 kB 32%]                             100% [Working]                                                    100% [35 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15,1 kB]
100% [36 Packages 5472 B/15,1 kB 36%]                             100% [Working]                                                    100% [36 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                          Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [297 kB]
100% [37 Translation-en 1080 B/297 kB 0%]                         100% [Working]                                                    100% [37 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                                            Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
100% [37 Translation-en bzip2 0 B]                                100% [Translation-en 21,7 kB] [37 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiti100% [37 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers]          100% [Waiting for headers]                                                                             
(etc)
/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Have you added any 3rd party software sources like PPAs?

Comment: Could you edit your question text to include the output in terminal?

Comment: Hi Antonio! For the future, consider using sites such as pastebin.com to share the terminal output in a readable way. Welcome on elemantaryOS StackExchange!

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing `apt` cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove duplicates from your repositories' list, go to `Settings`, then `Software & Updates` and hit the `Other software` tab. There, you can remove the duplicate repositories and uncheck the ones you don't want to pick updates from; if you're not concerned with elementary OS *development*, you can safely uncheck all the repositories containing the `(Source code)` label into the name. Then, try again to update, using the `Software Updater` utility or typing

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

into the `Terminal`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Internet connection.Go to system settings.Softwares and updates in that click for Ubuntu Software.see the option Download from and check the better server for your location ans set that.and Software updater will work.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade